# Delphi Работа с Sender

Tags: delphi

В методе `OnShow` нужно узнать название формы (компонента формы), с которой была открыта текущая форма.

В первой форме:

```
Form2.Show;
```

Во второй:

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender = Form1.Button then...
```

Увы, не работает. `Sender` — пустой.

Comment: стоит посмотреть в отладчике чему на самом деле равен `Sender`

Comment: Sender () т.е. он пустой

Comment: стоит добавить в вопрос откуда этот сендер берется, в каком событии?

Comment: В событии OnShow

Comment: `OnShow` формы которая открывается? скорее всего сендер и есть эта открывающаяся форма

Comment: Если так, то как быть?

Comment: что значит как? чтобы знать что делать - нужно знать что делается уже сейчас, и какой код как используется. Из вопроса видно только условие, из комментариев можно еще вытянуть имя события. **Вся необходимая** информация должна быть в вопросе: код как показывается форма, в каком обработчике все проверяется и т.д.

Comment: В первой форме Form2,Show; Во второй procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  is Sender = Form1.Button then...  Суть в том, что Sender = Form2. И нужно, что то другое.

Answer (score 3):

Переопределите во второй форме метод `Show`:

```
TForm2 = class (TForm)
// ...
public
   procedure Show(какие-то параметры);
// ...
end;

procedure TForm2.Show(какие-то параметры);
begin
  // тут что-то делаете с параметрами
  inherited Show;
end;
```

В простейшем случае вы можете передать сюда строку, которую затем сохранить в поле. Но с точки зрения ООП лучше передавать более содержательную информацию. Тут мне трудно посоветовать вам что-нибудь конкретное - я не знаю подробностей задачи.

Comment: Что это  переопределение?

Comment: @DmitrySokolov откройте учебник и прочитайте...

Answer (score 1):

Вы не полностью привели код. Скорее всего у вас что-то вида:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  Form2.Show; 
  ...
end;
```

Тогда вы можете его несколько модифицировать, например:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  Form2.Tag := Integer(Sender);
  Form2.Show;
  ...
end;
```

и дальше уже:

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Tag = Integer(Form1.Button) then...
```

Это если нужен самый простой вариант.